# Кэширование Google Maps на сайте

Tags: кэширование, google-maps-api

Оптимизирую сайт и последним звеном остался кеширование карты на сайте. Искал в гугле часами, так и ничего не нашел =/

Подсказку выдает сервис как Last-Modified.

Как можно кешировать карту?

Comment: А зачем?

Карта загружается напрямую от Google в браузер посетителя. Ваш сервер и его настройки кэширования не при делах. Если очень хочется, сделайте скриншот карты и отдавайте его вместо карты Гугл.

Answer (score 1):

Никак.